# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 when make openscad

Tags: boost, makefile, clang, openscad

I'm trying to install `openscad`, I have install all dependencies but when i'm trying to make `openscad` i've got this problem:

> $ make
>   clang++ -headerpad_max_install_names -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -stdlib=libc++ -arch x86_64 -o OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD objects/OffscreenContextCGL.o objects/CocoaUtils.o objects/PlatformUtils-mac.o objects/scintillaeditor.o objects/scadlexer.o objects/version_check.o objects/ProgressWidget.o objects/mathc99.o objects/linalg.o objects/Camera.o objects/handle_dep.o objects/value.o objects/expr.o objects/stackcheck.o objects/func.o objects/localscope.o objects/module.o objects/feature.o objects/node.o objects/context.o objects/modcontext.o objects/evalcontext.o objects/csgnode.o objects/CSGTreeNormalizer.o objects/CSGTreeEvaluator.o objects/Geometry.o objects/Polygon2d.o objects/clipper-utils.o objects/polyset-utils.o objects/GeometryUtils.o objects/polyset.o objects/polyset-gl.o objects/csgops.o objects/transform.o objects/color.o objects/primitives.o objects/projection.o objects/cgaladv.o objects/surface.o objects/control.o objects/render.o objects/text.o objects/dxfdata.o objects/dxfdim.o objects/offset.o objects/linearextrude.o objects/rotateextrude.o objects/printutils.o objects/fileutils.o objects/progress.o objects/parsersettings.o objects/stl-utils.o objects/boost-utils.o objects/PlatformUtils.o objects/LibraryInfo.o objects/nodedumper.o objects/traverser.o objects/GeometryEvaluator.o objects/ModuleCache.o objects/GeometryCache.o objects/Tree.o objects/DrawingCallback.o objects/FreetypeRenderer.o objects/FontCache.o objects/settings.o objects/rendersettings.o objects/highlighter.o objects/Preferences.o objects/OpenCSGWarningDialog.o objects/editor.o objects/GLView.o objects/QGLView.o objects/AutoUpdater.o objects/grid.o objects/builtin.o objects/calc.o objects/export.o objects/export_stl.o objects/export_amf.o objects/export_off.o objects/export_dxf.o objects/export_svg.o objects/export_nef.o objects/export_png.o objects/import.o objects/renderer.o objects/colormap.o objects/ThrownTogetherRenderer.o objects/svg.o objects/OffscreenView.o objects/fbo.o objects/system-gl.o objects/imageutils.o objects/lodepng.o objects/openscad.o objects/mainwin.o objects/UIUtils.o objects/Dock.o objects/FontListDialog.o objects/FontListTableView.o objects/launchingscreen.o objects/legacyeditor.o objects/LibraryInfoDialog.o objects/clipper.o objects/bucketalloc.o objects/dict.o objects/geom.o objects/mesh.o objects/priorityq.o objects/sweep.o objects/tess.o objects/imageutils-macosx.o objects/OpenCSGRenderer.o objects/cgalutils.o objects/cgalutils-applyops.o objects/cgalutils-project.o objects/cgalutils-tess.o objects/cgalutils-polyhedron.o objects/CGALCache.o objects/CGALRenderer.o objects/CGAL_Nef_polyhedron.o objects/cgalworker.o objects/Polygon2d-CGAL.o objects/AppleEvents.o objects/moc_scintillaeditor.o objects/moc_ProgressWidget.o objects/moc_QGLView.o objects/moc_MainWindow.o objects/moc_Preferences.o objects/moc_OpenCSGWarningDialog.o objects/moc_AboutDialog.o objects/moc_FontListDialog.o objects/moc_FontListTableView.o objects/moc_highlighter.o objects/moc_editor.o objects/moc_Dock.o objects/moc_AutoUpdater.o objects/moc_launchingscreen.o objects/moc_legacyeditor.o objects/moc_LibraryInfoDialog.o objects/moc_cgalworker.o objects/moc_EventFilter.o objects/qrc_openscad.o objects/parser_yacc.o objects/lexer_lex.o   -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/lib -framework Cocoa -framework ApplicationServices -lCGAL -lmpfr -lgmp -lopencsg -lGLEW -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_regex-mt -L/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.46.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -lglib-2.0 -lintl -liconv -L/usr/local/lib -lharfbuzz -L/usr/local/Cellar/freetype/2.6_1/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/fontconfig/2.11.1/lib -lfontconfig -lfreetype -L/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/lib -lqscintilla2 -framework QtOpenGL -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -F/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/lib -framework QtGui -framework QtCore -framework OpenGL -framework AGL 
>   ld: warning: object file (objects/OffscreenContextCGL.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being linked (10.7)
>   ld: warning: object file (objects/CocoaUtils.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being linked (10.7)
>   ld: warning: object file (objects/PlatformUtils-mac.o) was built for newer OSX version (10.10) than being linked (10.7)
>   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::get_mem_block()", referenced from:
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find_imp() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_all_states() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_startmark() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_alt() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_rep() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_char_repeat() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::match_set_repeat() in Tree.o
>         ...
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::put_mem_block(void*)", referenced from:
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find_imp() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::unwind_extra_block(bool) in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find_imp() in import.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::unwind_extra_block(bool) in import.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find_imp() in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::perl_matcher, std::__1::allocator > >, boost::regex_traits > >::find_imp() in import.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)", referenced from:
>         void boost::re_detail_106000::raise_error > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type) in Tree.o
>         void boost::re_detail_106000::raise_error > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type) in import.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)", referenced from:
>         boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const in Tree.o
>         boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const in import.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
>         std::__1::__wrap_iter boost::re_detail_106000::re_is_set_member, char, boost::regex_traits >, unsigned int>(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::re_detail_106000::re_set_long const*, boost::re_detail_106000::regex_data > > const&, bool) in Tree.o
>         std::__1::__wrap_iter boost::re_detail_106000::re_is_set_member, char, boost::regex_traits >, unsigned int>(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::re_detail_106000::re_set_long const*, boost::re_detail_106000::regex_data > > const&, bool) in import.o
>     "boost::re_detail_106000::cpp_regex_traits_implementation::transform(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
>         std::__1::__wrap_iter boost::re_detail_106000::re_is_set_member, char, boost::regex_traits >, unsigned int>(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::re_detail_106000::re_set_long const*, boost::re_detail_106000::regex_data > > const&, bool) in Tree.o
>         std::__1::__wrap_iter boost::re_detail_106000::re_is_set_member, char, boost::regex_traits >, unsigned int>(std::__1::__wrap_iter, std::__1::__wrap_iter, boost::re_detail_106000::re_set_long const*, boost::re_detail_106000::regex_data > > const&, bool) in import.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make: *** [OpenSCAD.app/Contents/MacOS/OpenSCAD] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the linker flags, it looks like you might have two different version of Boost installed. Mixing packages from different package managing frameworks makes such issues hard to track down. It could of course be a case of just needing "make clean", but hard to see from only the linker line.

I would recommend using the official build instructions to manage dependencies - those are pretty well maintained on OS X: https://github.com/openscad/openscad#building-for-mac-os-x